# unable to set custom image in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I'm trying to get the same result as shown in [here](https://nikshits.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/edittext-with-star-image-for-password/). But no image is getting set. Further I have to click on each edittext to type a number. I want the cursor to move to next edittext when previous is entered (maxLength=1). The "star1" is the image with star and "empty" is the image with no star. It would be really helpful if anyone can tell me what I've done wrong.

```css
activity_main

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
      <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >

              <TableRow 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                   

                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/ET1" 
                        android:layout_height="70dp" 
                        android:layout_width="70dp" 
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:background="@drawable/round" >
                    </EditText>

                   

                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/ET2"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"  
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:background="@drawable/round" >
                    </EditText>
                    
                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/ET3"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"  
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:background="@drawable/round" >
                    </EditText>
                    
                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/ET4"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"  
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:background="@drawable/round"  >
                    </EditText>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

       
    
    
    

</LinearLayout>
```

```html
Main Activity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
 EditText ET1, ET2, ET3, ET4;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  ET1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET1);
  ET2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET2);
  ET3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET3);
  ET4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET4);
 } // onCreate ends
 
 
 private void handleEdittextListner(){
        try {
            ET1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
                }
 
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
                }
 
               

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(ET1.getText().toString().trim().length()==1){
       
                        ET1.clearFocus();
                        ET2.requestFocus();
                        ET1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star1);
                    }
    }
            });
 
            ET2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
                }
 
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
                }
 
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(ET2.getText().toString().trim().length()==1){
 
                        ET2.clearFocus();
                        ET3.requestFocus();
                        ET2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star1);
                    }
                }
            });
            ET3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(ET3.getText().toString().trim().length()==1){
 
                        //ET1.clearFocus();
                        ET3.clearFocus();
                        ET4.requestFocus();
 
                        ET3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star1);
                    }
 
                }
            });
            
            ET4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(ET4.getText().toString().trim().length()==1){
                        ET4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star1);
                        //Hide keyboard
                        InputMethodManager imm =
                                (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ET4.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    }
 
                }
            });
            this.ET2.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
            {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View paramView, int paramInt, KeyEvent paramKeyEvent) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if ((paramKeyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(paramInt == 67) && (MainActivity.this.ET2.getText().length() == 0)){
                        ET1.requestFocus();
                        ET1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.empty);
                        ET1.setText("");
                    }
     return false;
    }
                
            });
            this.ET3.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
            {
                public boolean onKey(View paramView, int paramInt, KeyEvent paramKeyEvent)
                {
                    if ((paramKeyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(paramInt == 67) && (MainActivity.this.ET3.getText().length() == 0)){
                        ET2.requestFocus();
                        ET2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.empty);
                        ET2.setText("");
                    }
 
                    return false;
                }
            });
            this.ET4.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
            {
                public boolean onKey(View paramView, int paramInt, KeyEvent paramKeyEvent)
                {
                    if ((paramKeyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(paramInt == 67) && (MainActivity.this.ET4.getText().length() == 0)){
                        ET3.requestFocus();
                        ET3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.empty);
                        ET3.setText("");
                    }
 
                    return false;
                }
            });
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.toString();
        }
    }

 
} // Activity ends
```

Comment: You want to use this layout for password input?

Comment: This layout or any other. I just want to set custom image instead of .(dot) in such 4 EditText

Comment: I'm able to change dot to "*" by using PasswordTransformationMethod. But I want to set image instead of "*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your layout xml file set a white background color to your root layout element like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

After this in all the `EditText`s set the same color for the text:

```
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

After it do something like:

```
EditText ET1, ET2, ET3, ET4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ET1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET1);
    ET2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET2);
    ET3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET3);
    ET4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET4);

    ET1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.length() == 1){
                ET1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star1);
                if(ET2.requestFocus()){
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
    });

    ET2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.length() == 1){
                ET2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star1);
                if(ET3.requestFocus()){
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
    });

    ET3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.length() == 1){
                ET3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star1);
                if(ET4.requestFocus()){
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
    });

    ET4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.length() == 1){
                ET3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star1);
                InputMethodManager imm =
                        (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ET4.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

Try to put your `EditText` into a `FrameLayout`. In each `FrameLayout` set `android:background="@drawable/round"` like:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/round" >
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/ET1" 
        android:layout_height="70dp" 
        android:layout_width="70dp" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:inputType="number">
        </EditText>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the code. Now the images are working. But the border (android:background="@drawable/round") of EditText also disappears. I want the image to be inside the border. Is there any way for this?

Comment: Happy it helped you! See my edited answer for background problem solution.